# datepicker not populating the picker div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So i'm working with a template that was bought for admin area, however in the sample it appears, where as in my version it doesn't.

It adds

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></div>
```

However nothing else is in there, the ready state gets loaded, unique ID added but nothing else.

I have both jQuery and jQuery UI included via the CDN, any obvious things I'm missing why the div gets created but not populated?

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

UI field

```
<input type="text" class="simple_field pick_date hasDatepicker" />
```

Comment: You don't seem to have an element of class `datepicker`

Comment: Try `$(function() {
    $( ".hasDatepicker" ).datepicker();
});
`.

Comment: Ah, well that wasn't the problem, I had another jquery code that was assigning it to pick_date. Found the error and posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jQuery code is attempting to assign the datepicker to a field with class `datepicker`.  Your input does not have that class assigned.  It has a class `hasDatepicker`.  You need to change one or the other to match.

This should work:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".hasDatepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh *** just as I wrote this I realized that having 'hasDatepicker' class before page loaded mucks everything up!

Comment: Is this your answer or did you mean to make this a comment?